# Constant-time string equality check

Tags: java, strings, security

This is my attempt to answer [my own equally named question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37633688/581205). In this case, I need a method comparing two strings so that the running time is input independent.

```
// Not private in order to prevent optimizations.
static class Blackhole {
    private static void eat(long n) {
        dummy += n;
    }

    // Not private in order to prevent optimizations.
    static volatile long dummy;
}

public boolean areEqual(String input, String secret) {
    final int length = secret.length();
    // No need to keep the length secret.
    if (input.length() != length) {
        return false;
    }
    long delta = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        // Any char is interpreted as a non-negative number.
        // Xoring such numbers preserves non-negativity.
        // The result depends on every input bit, so no short-circuit is possible.
        // Overflow is impossible, therefore diff is zero <=> all chars are the same.
        delta += input.charAt(i) ^ secret.charAt(i);
    }
    Blackhole.eat(delta);
    return delta == 0;
}
```

It's a really short snippet and I'm mainly interested in ensuring that it really works in constant time.  In particular, I'm afraid that the loop could indeed get optimized to something like

> ```
> int i = 0
> for (; ; ++i) {
>     if (input.charAt(i) != secret.charAt(i)) break;
> }
> for (; i < length; ++i) {
>     delta += input.charAt(i) ^ secret.charAt(i);
> }
> ```

where the first loop could be faster on some architectures, as -- after unrolling -- it translates to load, xor with memory, and a conditional jump. Assuming some future architecture capable of executing 6 instructions per cycle when there are no data dependencies and no mispredictions, it could be a win. Or the JIT could believe, it makes sense...

Concerning the `Blackhole`, I wonder if `volatile` is necessary. I didn't want to depend on JMH nor copy this [monster](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/b995ada2e6b4/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/infra/Blackhole.java).

---

In the meantime I've got an idea avoiding volatile writes nearly perfectly

```
    private static void eat(long n) {
        if (n == dummy) {
            dummy = new SecureRandom().nextLong();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Side question: if you're trying to prevent _timing attacks_ then why you say _no need to keep length secret_? To determine exact string length Isn't it the very first step an attacker performs? Then he will go on timing response for each character...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I don't care about the length. Keeping it secret would be slightly better, but the secret is a case-sensitive alphanumeric string of length 37, giving `52**37 = 2e66` possibilities. Gaining or losing a factor of 10 (or a million) just doesn't count.

Comment: `intern()`? :-D

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, we cannot rely on arguments that the "compiler isn't smart enough to do that" because that may change tomorrow. We need to base our assessment of the code on what the compiler is and isn't allowed to do.

Given two input strings and a yes/no return if the string match, any program performing the function can be transformed into the trivial short-circuited for-loop. Provided that there isn't anything prohibiting the compiler from doing the transform.

Will writing the sum of xor differences to a volatile prevent the transform? Maybe, it depends on the execution model and guarantees of volatile in Java. In C++ under the as-if rule all writes and reads to/from volatile memory regions must occur in the same order as-if the program was executed according to the wording in the standard (somewhat simplified but that's the gist of it). So for C++ this would work; However I'm unsure if Java has the same guarantee. For C++ this limitation is natural because it must be able to interface with device drivers and bus addresses where writes and reads cannot be re-ordered or omitted. But Java does none of the kind and as such I wouldn't be terribly surprised if volatile has a more lax meaning in Java.

What about `SecureRandom`? Well it is really just volatile reads from `/dev/urand` in disguise to get the seed, the rest is deterministic which the compiler that compiled the JVM isn't allowed to reorder or remove, but what the JIT is allowed to do in this context is beyond me. It is conceivable that the JIT can deduce that the read from `/dev/urand` will not affect the program in an observable way and it will remove the code all together.

If the volatile keyword doesn't have the same meaning in Java as in C++ I believe that doing this kind of processing in Java in a reliable and guaranteed way is difficult. I would consider a hand written loop in assembler in a JNI library, this is guaranteed by your C/C++/assembler to not be fudged in any way.

I'm sorry this isn't an authoritative yes/no answer on correctness, but I hope that it is of some help any way.

Comment: *But Java does none of the kind and as such I wouldn't be terribly surprised if volatile has a more lax meaning in Java.* - I'm not sure, but isn't communication with other threads equally demanding as communication with HW? Quite a few Java concurrent data structures rely on `volatile` as it's way faster than other synchronization primitives. +++ My only reason for `SecureRandom` was not to provide any additional clue to the attacker as they might see the delay cause by the assignment `dummy = new SecureRandom().nextLong()` and learn about `n` if the previously assigned value was predictable.

Comment: @maaartinus JLS §8.3.1.4: `"A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable"`. This is weaker than the "as-if" rule for C/C++ because if no thread observes the variable, it is in practice allowed to omit the stores to it.

Comment: Interesting point. So e.g. when the JVM runs a single thread, it could ignore all `volatile`s and `synchronized` and whatever. Funny!

Answer (score 4):

I'm sorry to burst the bubble, but achieving "constant time" in any environment where the compiler, a bytecode interpreter, or even the processor might optimize your code, is delusional.

This only works on very simple architectures where you control both the machine code, and know the precise hardware characteristics. With a Java compiler + Java VM + unknown hardware arch, you are far off from these requirements.

I'm serious about the hardware. Worst case would e.g. be the JVM inserting a NEQ test around the character XOR and addition, which could trigger the branch prediction in the processor to go onto the "fast path" as soon as it encounters the first 2-3 equal characters. That's not even in the code you've written, but it's a sensible optimization to be added by the JVM.

This is not even just about the "Blackhole" potentially being eliminated by the compiler, but being unable to assume even constant time for the actual comparison.

If you want constant time, there is only a single legit solution: Use a clock and then wait to enforce a constant execution time. Beware that in concurrent systems, getting the system into a state of starvation on CPU time will still allow an attacker to estimate the effective cost based on raw throughput.

Adding a random wait on authentication failures as suggested by others is a good start, but also suffers from the aforementioned issue. This is only reliable as long as the authentication is additionally rate limited to avoid the possibility of being CPU limited.

Comment: I disagree with you concerning adding NEQ test. There's no place for it as I'm computing `delta += input.charAt(i) ^ secret.charAt(i)`. At this point, the characters being equals or not just can't matter as a sum is to be computed. The sum gets used in two ways later: Once in a blackhole, hopefully in a way that can't be eliminated. Because of this, there's no reason to use a short-circuit for the boolean as after having computed `int result`, the simplest and fastest way is to `return delta == 0`.

Comment: Sure there is. `if(char1 != char2) delta += char1  ^ char2` yields equivalent result to plain `delta += char1 ^ char2`. Except that the former avoids an unconditional memory write, so it is a legit optimization to happen. You won't see this happening with current Oracle JVMs, I think, but likely with ones optimizing more aggressively.

Comment: But there's no memory write as `delta` is in a register... most probably not in any CPU for which avoiding memory writes would be a win. Maybe x86 in 32 bit mode could ran out of registers, but even then this optimization would cause a slowdown due to conditional branching.... but you might be right: See my update.

Comment: "Adding a random wait on authentication failures as suggested by others is a good start" - sadly not unless you can directly use HPET and interrupts. Artificial delays on almost any platform are subject to the whims of the thread scheduler and timer limitations of the operating system; common sleep functions usually have a granularity of at least 16ms and any random delays produced with them can be low-passed out of a sufficiently large timing sample, or counteracted using cluster analysis.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid *clever* compiler optimizations simply instruct it that you want to count *differences instead of matches*:

```
int differences = 0, matches = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    if ((input.charAt(i) ^ secret.charAt(i)) != 0)
        ++differences;
    else
        ++matches;
}
```

Then let's use `differences` value to call a function which side effect cannot be ignored (idea stolen from your updated question about `Blackhole`), this is just an example but something smarter may be done for sure:

```
try
{
    new SecureRandom().nextLong(differences);
}
catch (IllegalArgumentException) {
    // If argument is 0 (what we want for an exact match)
    // then nextLong() throws this exception
    return true;
}

return false;
```

In chat it has been widely discussed if/when compiler is allowed to perform some optimizations. I won't repeat that discussion here but also note that you may simply *use* loop counter outside the loop to stop any compliant compiler to apply any short-circuit:

```
int differences = 0, i= 0;
for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    // ...
}

if (i != length - 1)
    throw new Exception("..."); // Is it better Error here?
```

I'm using `if`/`else` instead of `differences += ... ? 1 : 0` to avoid JIT compiler to possibly generate `CMOV` instruction (or equivalent on your target architecture). Use `matches` somewhere to avoid compiler to optimize it away. You can `^` it with `input.length()` and add it to `differences`, for example.

---

Note that to determine exact string length is the very first step of a *timing attack*, only after that the attacker will start to work character by character. Your first check about string length matching will vanish 1/3rd of your work, let's work around it. Comparison time is always *dictated* by `input` string, this won't give any hint to an attacker about `secret` length.

```
int differences = 0, matches = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= input.length(); ++i) {
    char secretChar = input.charAt(Math.min(input.length() - 1, i));
    if ((input.charAt(i) ^ secretChar) != 0)
        ++differences;
    else
        ++matches;
}
```

Now we have to change our final check to be sure length matched (otherwise a partial match or an empty string will be compared as equal). We can simply add `input.length() ^ secret.length()` to difference count, we just want it's zero:

```
    new SecureRandom().nextLong(differences + (input.length() ^ secret.length()));
```

---

Side note about Unicode: this code (as well as original one) is not really *Unicode-friendly*. A grapheme isn't equivalent to `char` and string comparison should be performed with normalized inputs but let's keep it simple, for now.

---

If timing attack is really a common problem to address you may consider to add a **random delay** for failed attempts. In this case you may drop this *constant time string comparison* and simply make timing *useless*. Note that delay has to be short enough to don't make DoS easier but sufficiently long to *confuse* attacker when performing *exact* time measurement. 3-4 milliseconds may be a good starting point for further investigations. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/a/30785/80859.

---

Note that redesigning your code you can take a different approach. First pre-compute a good **hash function** for secret password.

```
int secretPasswordHash = Hash(secret);
```

Now your function may be:

```
public boolean areEqual(String input, String secret) {
    if (secretPasswordHash != Hash(input))
        return false;

    if (input.length() != secret.length())
        return false;

    // With a good hash you really do not need constant-time comparison...
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i)
        if (input.charAt(i) != secret.charAt(i))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the JIT is not allowed to remove the instantiation of `SecureRandom`? Sure it has side effects, but they are not observable in the sense that you cannot tell from the execution of the program whether or not a `SecureRandom` object was created or not. I would find it unlikely that the JIT would do this, but I cannot rule it.

Comment: @Emily compiler can't arbitrarily remove an object instantiation for a non primitive type. First of all because it has always an important side effect (even for an _empty_ object): run-time memory allocation. Any function call without an used return value (let's say you create you create a file) won't have an _observable effect_ from the execution of the program but obviously compiler won't remove it...

Comment: Can you point me to a reference that says the JIT isn't allowed to remove an instantiation of an object? In your example the created file is an observable effect. The run-time memory allocation isn't observable if it is not used. It doesn't change the result of the program.

Comment: You're seeing this from the wrong point of view, optimizations must be allowed...not vice-versa. Which parts of the standard says that compiler may remove an arbitrary part of your code? Memory allocation has a very observable effect (where other objects will be allocated and...well try to allocate 10 GB of unused objects). Even ignoring memory allocation: why compiler should remove an object allocation and a method call?! According to which rule? Oh, BTW it has visible side effects (even for a very smart compiler) because it may throw an exception which we catch...

Comment: I come from C++, where the compiler is *allowed* to do **any** optimization as long as the program's accesses to volatile memory (files, terminals, display memory, etc) occurs in the same order as-if executed without optimization (somewhat simplified). Are you saying Java has different rules for this? I would love to read up on what the JIT is allowed to do and not but I can't find any references.

Comment: But it has such effect, think about a function foo() which just allocate some memory and then deallocate it: void foo() { void* ptr = malloc(100); free(ptr); }. Is a C compiler allowed to optimize away a function call to foo()? No. In this case Java compiler has the same issue: it doesn't know if an object allocation will fail or not and it doesn't know what that method does (imagine to return those allocated block and...call a method to memset to zero). It's useless but compiler can't determine it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41252/discussion-between-emily-l-and-adriano-repetti).

Comment: You have an `if` in the first block. That's definitely not advisable if you're aiming for constant-time performance.

Comment: @PeterTaylor you're right, so "busy" focusing on other stuff to don't see the obvious, thanks!

Comment: A random delay is no perfect solution, it just [adds some more randomness](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/96489/4228). +++ @PeterTaylor That's why I use just `+=` and `^` in the loop.

Comment: @maaartinus in that post they explain why a random delay is useless if you can have both measures X (valid) and Y (invalid). In this case they can have only a measure for Y. I ignore the other point about delay for legitimate users because it's just few milliseconds and only if they type wrong password. See also [Is it reasonable to prevent timing attacks by using fixed processing time](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/30785/80859). Just a side note: you may also perform this task in two steps, first calculating a long hash of both strings and then **comparing hashes**...

Comment: I disagree with the first part. Here, the attacker has a timing for first char right (and something wrong later) and first char wrong (many such cases) and they can eliminate randomness by repeating the measurement (which may get damn impractical). +++ Thx for the link. +++ calculating a long hash - seems to make sense, too.

Comment: This implementation does not account for branch prediction and cache invalidation timing attacks.

Comment: @Polynomial branch prediction doesn't apply, both branches have equal code to execute (increment a variable, which BTW will be probably compiled - if compiled to native - to a couple of ADD+CMOV). About cache invalidation...sorry, probably by knowledge about this is too poor but I don't see how it can be applied to string comparison (especially given that OP _doesn't care_ to reveal string length)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Branch prediction does apply. It's nothing to do with whether the target line of code is functionally the same. The processor attempts to guess, ahead of time, which way a conditional jump (e.g. `jnz`) will go. The heuristics are incredibly complicated and mostly undocumented, but the generic rule is that the compiler will always presume that jumps which go to lower addresses will be taken (due to loop bounds checks). When a branch is taken *against* the prediction (i.e. branch prediction failure) the instruction pipeline is invalidated, increasing the execution time.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Since the branch decision will be based upon data (e.g. `test rsi, rdi; jnz charsEqual`) each failure in branch prediction may leak information about whether the characters were equal. This is of particular concern in power analysis cases, since parent cache fetches are easily identifiable, but it's also applicable to timing attack cases. In fact, a case where each character is alternately equal and not equal (e.g. "aaaaaaaa" and "abababab") the branch prediction may fail on every comparison and increase the execution time a fair amount.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti You're right that a `cmov` wouldn't produce quite as drastic of a difference, but it's still not ideal. The correct implementation is to maintain a state and simply bitwise-or it with the xor of the two characters at each step. This removes all conditional operations from the loop body and produces a fully linear, time-constant comparison.

Comment: @Polynomial if you have two CMOVs (one for _right_ and one for _wrong_) then there isn't any significative difference between wrong and right guesses and branch predictor won't affect performance (because...well...there aren't branches). There is just TEST or CMP and then a couple of ADD and CMOV (yes we all d*** want a CADD, maybe). If compiler will ever use MMX or SIMD...I can't imagine outcomes but I'd guess it'll mess up measurements even more

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Perhaps you're right, but I'd rather take the pragmatic approach and remove all potentially-conditional (note: cmov *is* conditional) operations from the loop body entirely. Translating the problem into a series of linear operations is safer against other attack types (e.g. DPA) than a cmov.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I also object to your note about adding random timings. This is a worthless defence against all but the most trivially naive timing attacks. By treating the timing values as a continuous signal rather than discrete points, one can apply low-pass or comb filtering to reject the larger timing discrepancies and recover the much shorter timing noise.

Comment: @Polynomial I agree with you about random delays. To build an (almost) fixed-time computation is pretty hard (however delay in conjuction with existing constant-time code may help if carefully chosen)

Comment: @Polynomial I disagree with adding random delays being worthless. The noise doesn't make the signal impossible to recover, but it may make it much harder. You may need a thousand tries to recover a character, but after one hundred you get kicked out. A much better idea would be to add unpredictable input-dependent delays which are independent of the secret to all failed attempts like `sleep(hmac(anotherSecret, input))`.

Comment: @maaartinus An input-dependent delay is inherently a side-channel vulnerability, albeit not a very useful one in the case you described (but critical if someone misimplements the code with `anotherSecret` being the same as the main secret). But my previous point still stands - artificial delays using `sleep` and other timing functions will be orders of magnitude longer than timing jitter in a cryptographic function, and as such will be utterly trivial to low-pass out of a timing sample. Random delay approaches are fundamentally broken.

Comment: @maaartinus I cannot advise strongly enough to avoid attempting to write your own constant-time functionality, even in C as an external library. The problem is incredibly complicated as evidenced by the answers and comments here. Even *if* you fully control the compiler and verify the resultant assembly on every build across all target platforms, there are still platform-specific cases that need special attention (see the NEQ example from Ext3h) and even CPU-specific issues (see Intel's processor errata for some horror stories). Truly time-constant code is *incredibly* difficult to achieve.

Comment: @Polynomial I really can't see how you want to trivially filter out noise which is correlated with the input because of it being orders of magnitude higher than the signal. But in case you really could, another idea: Add `Arrays.equals(hmac(s2, input), hmac(s3, input))` in order to get noise of proper magnitude. +++ Advising against writing my own is of little use when there are no alternatives. `MessageDigest#equals` is worse. +++ The only possibly better algorithm, I've seen is comparing `hmac(k, input)` with `hmac(k, secret)` where the way from timing to characters is blocked by the hmac.

Comment: @maaartinus If you treat the timing changes as a continuous signal, like an audio wave, you just run a low-pass filter over it. It's incredibly trivial to filter out. You can also apply an offset-removal approach since artificial delays produced with common delay routines are usually quantised to 16ms blocks due to low precision timers on x86 hardware (unless you use HPET + interrupt).

Comment: @maaartinus You keep coming up with potential ideas, but is it worth considering that, perhaps, you're not well-versed enough in the theory and practicality of timing attacks to come to an informed decision over what is and is not a good defence? Just as I am not well-versed enough in infrastructure design to conceive an appropriate load balancer setup for a large-scale application. In this case I *do* have practical experience of identifying and exploiting timing attacks (I've been paid to do so in recent times, so I guess I'm a professional?) so it may be worth heeding my advice.

Comment: @maaartinus Also, if an appeal-to-authority argument might sway you... [here's my Security SE profile](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/5400/polynomial) (not that it's entirely relevant here)

Comment: @Polynomial Low-pass and offset-removal - thanks, understood. My last point about `hmac` - I've found it somewhere and I believe, it's right. But I'm no expert and I know it. +++ I looked at your profile and answers long time ago and I've been well aware of you being an expert on SE. I didn't know that you've worked on timing-attack prevention. That makes me listen even harder to what you're saying. Believe me, I do listen. If you told me to call `x.y.z.ConstantTimeComparer.isEqual`, I may keep discussing it for ages, but I'd put it in my code *now*. However, you did not.

Comment: @Polynomial Normally, I'd use what's provided, but nothing is. 0. Is there a solution, you'd recommend? 1. Do we agree, that `MessageDigest.isEqual` is worse than my attempt? 2. Do we agree that adding noise which is independent of any real secret can do no harm? Obviously, making the code more complicated makes it subject to more bugs, but as long as it's trivial, the risk is tiny. Moreover, when done in a stupid way, it may be useless. 3. What do you think about the idea of comparing `hmac(k, input)` with `hmac(k, secret)` (where `k` is a key used only here) instead of the direct comparison?

Comment: @maaartinus The double-HMAC trick can technically work, but it isn't ideal because a leak of the secondary key would break the entire solution due to `Array.equals` using early-out optimisation. I would recommend `MessageDigest.isEqual` against the two HMACs as long as the JVM you're targeting is newer than SE 6 Update 17 (this is not guaranteed in many cases). If you need portable code and can't write and verify an external constant-time check in C/ASM, check that `System.getProperty("java.version")` returns 1.6.0_17 or later and use MessageDigest.isEqual if so, otherwise throw a fatal error.

Comment: @maaartinus Just keep in mind that `MessageDigest.isEqual` *may* not be safe in JVMs/platforms other than the official Oracle one, so it may also be worth verifying that too via the `java.vendor` property.

Comment: @maaartinus I took the liberty of posting this as a new answer.

Comment: @Polynomial I'm on Java 8, so SE 6 won't run my code. Verifying `java.vendor`, OK. I [can see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626494/581205) that the previous implementation used to be horrible. Fixed, but it still may get optimized to a non-constant-time method, right? That's why I started thinking about using the Blackhole. Actually, `MessageDigest.isEqual`could be secure if it was treated as an [intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19892404/581205) as then the generated assembly would be known. But there's no such intrinsic. `+++` The HMACs can be compared using `MessageDigest.isEqual`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63993/discussion-between-maaartinus-and-polynomial).

Answer (score 1):

After looking into this further, I have what seems to be the most sensible solution for the case where you need portable (i.e. cross-platform and cross-architecture) code.

First, check `System.getProperty("java.version")` returns "1.6.0_17" or later and that `System.getProperty("java.vendor")` returns "Oracle Corporation". This ensures that you're running code on Oracle Java with a version number *after* the constant-time patch was applied to `MessageDigest.isEqual`.

After this check has been completed, you are safe to use `MessageDigest.isEqual`. If the check fails, exit the program with a fatal error and do not perform the check. The implementation within Oracle Java SE 6 Update 17 and later is written as a constant-time check which is *not* implemented in Java bytecode, but rather in C. This is as close as you're going to get to a constant-time check in Java without sacrificing portability.

The only other semi-sane way to go with this is to wrap libsodium via JNI and do all of your crypto in there, utilising the [constant time helpers](https://download.libsodium.org/doc/helpers/) for equality checks, although this largely restricts you to x86_32, x86_64, and ARM architectures.

Comment: The only thing I'm missing is a pointer supporting your claim about the intrinsication of `MessageDigest.isEqual`.

Comment: See the updates at the bottom of this article: https://codahale.com/a-lesson-in-timing-attacks/

Comment: `MessageDigest.isEqual` was and [still is implemented](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/2f301425af62/src/java.base/share/classes/java/security/MessageDigest.java#l457) in pure Java. Unfortunately. It baffles me that Java doesn’t provide a _standard, guaranteed_constant-time comparison method. They did change it from a short-circuit algorithm to a seems-constant-time-in-source-code one, but not to C, and you’ll notice the OP of this question already knew this at the time of asking if you follow the link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that people seem to have neglected is the issue of branches within the loop body. Taking a branch may invalidate the instruction pipeline, leading to timing differences based on the contents of data. While these differences are subtle, they're important if you're looking to build a hardened constant-time comparison algorithm.

A pseudocode implementation is as follows:

```
int compareLength = min(a.length(), b.length());

if (compareLength == 0)
{
    // at least one string is empty (zero length)
    // so if they're both the same length, both are empty (equal)
    return a.length() == b.length();
}

int state = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < compareLength; i++)
{
    state |= a.charAt(i) ^ b.charAt(i);
}

return state == 0;
```

Apologies for any syntax issues, my Java is rusty.

The benefits of this approach are:

- Loop contains only linear fixed-time operations (OR, XOR) which removes data-conditional branches.
- The use of linear operations prevents aggressive compiler optimisation (e.g. early-out once inner equality check results cannot affect the function's returned value).
- Looping over the shortest string length makes it more difficult to discern the exact length of both strings.
- On very large strings, this algorithm is faster than using `if` inside the loop, as no cache invalidation occurs (branch predictor should always be correct for the loop bound condition).

That said, if the strings are particularly sensitive, you should consider whether they should be string objects in the first place. My understanding is that Java strings are immutable managed objects which have no disposal guarantee. This means that you end up with various copies and fragments of the string in the managed heap without any guarantee of when they'll be cleaned up, if ever. For sensitive values you should consider storing them raw, in the unmanaged heap, and ensuring that all code paths correctly wipe the associated memory (e.g. via a finally block).

In fact, Java is a pretty horrible language to do this kind of thing in, because the JIT compiler is free to do whatever it likes to your code with all sorts of horrible abominations of optimisation. I would suggest moving this function to a native DLL with optimisation disabled.

Comment: No, this will break constant time check. In _theory_ when state variable changes to a non-zero value compiler may short-circuit loop and return immediately (an _optimization_ to do not execute full loop, it _may_ even be done by javac but without PGO it's a blind-guess, JIT compiler has much more context).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Surely the compiler can't implement such aggressive optimisation? For example, how does it infer that the `charAt` call can't throw an exception or produce some other side effect at a later call than when it decides to early-out? If it were capable of such an optimisation then all bets are off; even returning the value of `state` would not resolve the issue as the calling conditional would surely be identified and the optimisation would remain. If this is the case, I'd argue that Java as a language is incapable of constant-time operations entirely.

Comment: It has been a strong debate in chat! Someone has even more radical ideas about what a compiler _may_ (in theory) do. I think it won't go too far because its knowledge is fairly limited (and it's not a theorem prover) but for _internal_ methods it has a lot of knowledge. It may even do bounds checking just once. I don't mean it does it NOW (and especially for this code snippet) but it's surely free to do it in future (code is still correct, just...faster)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti It seems that this is an intractable problem with Java's JIT compiler, then. I've edited to suggest moving the algorithm out to a native DLL, since in C or a similar language this can be controlled, analysed, and instrumented once by the developer to ensure security.

Comment: Java compiler is in theory allowed to do almost what it wants. There are however _limits_ (unknown native code and I/O) it can't touch. I agree, with a native DLL you have a finer control and it's probably a better choice for this kind of tasks.